# Graph of pdf and calculate moments

Tags: statistics

> http://www.dumpt.com/img/viewer.php?file=0pt0l719ug05g1r09sly.jpg
>
> The diagram in the link shows the graph of a probability density function. Given that the mean is zero, express $b$ in terms of $a$. Calculate the second and third moments in terms $a$.

I have found that $b=2a$. I am not sure how to find moments from a pdf graph.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure your value for $b$ is wrong. How did you get it?

There's enough information to find the pdf. From there you can find moments.

Comment: I used $-ac+(1/2)bc=0$ because the mean is zero.

Comment: actually that's wrong. I need the equation for the pdf.

Comment: The problem is (as I assume you mean by 'that's wrong') that $ac+(1/2)bc=0$ *doesn't* make the mean zero. Note that you need to make the area 1 and the mean 0, which lets you get both $b$ and $c$ in terms of $a$. Once you have $b$ and $c$ you can find the pdf (which is still depends on $a$) quite easily. There, $a$ takes the role of a parameter. Imagine that given $b$, and $c$ and some particular value for $a$, the density is $f(x)$. How would you work out the mean if you knew what $f$ was?